# How can I repair a swollen tire allowing visibility on the inner tube (picture provided)?

Tags: tire, repair

I have a new problem on my bike which occured after patching my inner tube. Since I put the patch on, my tire is pushed out away from the rim near the intake valve (not near the patch). In the picture below, you can see the inner tube between the rim and the tire (partially hidden from view by snow). This is the case only on that spot, and only on that side. I can still ride the bike (I've been riding it like this for two days) but I can feel a small bump every time my wheel make a full rotation. Mostly, I'm afraid it will break soon.

The question: What's causing this problem and how can I solve it?

[image]

Comment: Do yourself a favor and don't ride it around until it is fixed. Seriously.

Comment: Respect for fixing your bike in the snow.

Comment: @Shawn did you get an answer to this in the end? I have exactly the same problem, following a puncture repair, and like your case, none of the above suggestions apply. There is no hole or rip in the outer tire, all that's happened is that the inner has been repaired. I have been assuming that maybe the inner tube is too big and is less flexible following the repair.... this presumes that I just never noticed it before. Any thoughts? Thanks, Dave

Comment: @Dave I didn't get anything more than what is in the answers and comments here, no.

Comment: @Dave to be clear, Daniel R Hicks' answer did work for me, see the comments

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The picture does not make the situation totally clear, but it appears that tube is not centered in the tire, and the tire is not centered over the rim.  This tends to happen especially near the stem, because the thicker part of the tube gets caught between tire and rim and prevents the tire from sliding into place.

Deflate the tire, then press the valve stem in about 1/2 or 3/4 inch while you wiggle the tire to get it around and under tube.  Inflate slowly, and if you see the same thing again, repeat the process.  It may take two or three tries to get things lined up..

(If, on the other hand, what we're seeing is the sidewall failing and the tube pressing through the sidewall then the tire's toast.)

Comment: I believe it's neither... You see, while the tire is properly seated in the rim at first, it gets pushed out  by the tube as I inflate it (I've tried this many times). Also, the tire is not ripped at all.

Comment: I wouldn't even ever consider riding on the tire like this. Get a new tire ASAP... I doubt I would even ride to a bike shop to get a new one.

Comment: @Shawn - Well, give what I suggested a shot.  If that doesn't fix it then probably the bead is stretched and you need to replace the tire.  As Benzo says, it's not safe to ride like that.

Comment: (You might have stretched the bead by using excessive force to re-seat the tire after patching the tube.)

Comment: @Shawn: it surely looks ripped.

Comment: @Benzo What's the worst that can happen? A flat tire? I can live with that. As.. I forget who said: "Don't panic, be wary!"

Comment: A blowout is very likely, and can be disastrous at any sort of speed, or while negotiating traffic.

Comment: A blowout on icy roads at that. If it is your front wheel, the risk is far greater. Tires and tubes are cheap and expendable.

Comment: Thanks @DanielRHicks, your solution of re-inflating the tire with the stem pushed 1/2 an inch inside the tire worked. Sorry for the delay, I had to buy a new pump (the tube from the one I had ripped because of the cold)

Answer (score 4):

As I already wrote in the comment, the tire looks ripped to me (as Rider_X suggests, that the bead has torn away). It would be helpful if the camera's focus was on the tire instead on the house behind. :)

As you are in a city, you can buy a new tire and replace it. Easy. But these kind of things sometimes happen when you are on the road, away from bike shops and services. If you don't have spare tire in that case, you may perform an emergency repair so that the tire and tube can hold for some time:

http://voices.yahoo.com/bike-skills-repair-torn-open-tire-8524921.html

The idea is to place something (the article suggest denim, but I've heard people using pieces of old worn out tire, without the bead of course) between the ripped tire and the tube, and then wrap them both tightly, using a duct tape, rope, wire, whatever comes in handy. Riding will not be pleasant, but it's better than pushing your bike with a flat.

Comment: My thinking is that what looks like torn stuff is really just the "flash" along the bead.  If you look farther down the rim you can see that most of the darker-colored band disappears behind the rim.  But the picture is poor, so it's hard to tell with any certainty.

Comment: @DanielRHicks Thanks for explaining that, nobody seems to believe me when I say the tire is not torn. As for the picture, it was taken with my cell phone and I didn't manage to get better quality.

Comment: @Shawn - But if repeated attempts at deflating the tire, pushing in the stem, and reseating the tire do not result in a proper fit then likely the bead has been damaged and the tire needs to be replaced.

Answer (score 1):

It really looks like the bead has torn away from the tire.  You can verify by taking the tire off and looking for a metal wire (like a big loop) is exposed in the corresponding area.  If it is bad you will even be able to insert your finger between the beed and tire.

If this is the case, it is not repairable and is dangerous to ride on.  Without an intact bead, the tire will not properly adhere to the rim when inflated (consistent with your description).

As @Daniel R Hicks stated if you ride on this and it blows it can be disastrous (e.g., a blow out on a corner where the tire is under more pressure).

Comment: The bead is fine in my case, but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've thrown away tires that were no where near as frightful as this one looks.  ***ANY attempt at salvaging the tire or tube is ill advised.***

I'd also carefully inspect the wheel rim as well to see if there is any deformation, warping or splitting.  Loss of a tire while moving is a potential visit to the emergency room or the morgue.

Answer (score -1):

As pointed out in other answers, the true solution is to get a new tire but you can for a short time reinforce the worn section of the sidewall with a folded dollar bill.

Just fold the bill into thirds and place it between the tire and the tube.  I am not sure why (or if) a dollar works better than other materials but this is what I was always told and this is what I have always used.

Comment: This would work if the tire had a hole, which is not my case.

Comment: It seems to work even if the sidewall is not torn but just weakened.  I think it just distributes the pressure over a larger area.  It is not a long term solution but it will help while you ride your bike to the shop to get a new tire.